# c++11 uniform initialization doesn't work with "g++ -std=c++0x"

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++, uniform-initialization

I have a class that declares this public method:

```
virtual std::vector<float> operator()(const std::vector<float>& = {});
```

which uses uniform initialization (here just `{}`), a feature from c++11. This doesn't give me any problem when compiling with `clang++ -std=c++11`. But when I use `g++ -std=c++0x` I get this:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
```

Isn't the `-std=c++0x` option supposed bring me c++11 support?

The compiler doesn't give me any error when declaring the method using standard c++ like this:

```
virtual std::vector<float> operator()(const std::vector<float>& = std::vector<float>());
```

I am using g++ 4.6 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Not sure what you are asking `std=c++0x` is not c++11 support, it is pre-11 as understood by gcc developers back at the day of 4.6. If you want full c++11, use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug.  it compiles in 4.7.3 and above: https://godbolt.org/g/gy9Kb5

Comment: Now there is c++11/c++14, there is no point to use c++0x/c++1y. and once c++17 is out c++1z would be unneeded too.

Comment: @SergeyA I think g++ 4.6 doesn't have the `-std=c++11` flag (I get `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'`)

Comment: Also, I get the same error when trying to use the `override` keyword.

Comment: For C++11, you need g++-4.7 or higher.

Comment: @George, time to upgrade than!

Comment: But [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html) they say that the `-std=c++0x` option gives experimental support for initializer lists.

Comment: @SergeyA Well.. I would :) if it wasn't that it's the compiler of my university's lab (and they say I can use c++11 in the lab with g++ 4.6). Whatever, thanks to all and I will ask to my admins. Then if possible I'll try to give an answer to the question.

Comment: @George experimental support != working support.

Comment: @George, you can also compile your own version of GCC from sources and use it. You do not need to be root for this.

Comment: It's an assignement: they want me to use this specific version of g++. But it strikes me that it doesn't work even for the `override` keyword: experimental support != not working for *every* c++11 feature (@NathanOliver)

Comment: They were still adding features at that time.  C++11 was huge change for C++.  You can't expect experimental support to have all of the C++11 features and all of them working as expected.  regular expression are part of C++11 but they were not supported until gcc 4.9 and not really stable until gcc 5.  If you are stuck with gcc 4.6 then you will just have to learn to live with the limited support it offers for C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [GCC 4.7 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html):

> G++ now accepts the `-std=c++11`, `-std=gnu++11`, and `-Wc++11-compat` options, which are equivalent to `-std=c++0x`, `-std=gnu++0x`, and `-Wc++0x-compat`, respectively.

From the [C++11 in GCC project page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11):

> **GCC 4.8.1** was the first feature-complete implementation of the 2011 C++ standard, previously known as C++0x.

---

Bad news, you need to upgrade your compiler to get working C++11 support.

Answer (score 0):

GCC 4.6 doesn't support all of the c++11 features:

> GCC provides experimental support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support can be enabled with the -std=c++0x.

I suggest that you upgrade to the latest GCC version, and compile with the flag `-std=c++11` or even `-std=c++14`